# Different approaches for finding the max 'k' values in a Python list for implementing knn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, knn

I tried to find the max 3 values in the list for implementing my knn model.
While trying to do so, I did it using the method that was intuitive to me the code was something as follows
`

```
first_k = X_train['distance'].sort_values().head(k)
prediction = first_k.value_counts().idxmax()
```

`
The first_k list contains the first k elements from the sorted values of the distance column. Prediction is what the model will return at last.

Another approach I found on the internet was this
`

```
prediction = y_train[X_train["distance"].nsmallest(n=k).index].mode()[0]
```

`
The second approach yields the correct results and my approach did not work as intended. Can someone explain to me why my approach did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the usage of `.index` after the method `nsmallest(n=k)` in the alternative approach. What you are doing in your code is the following:

1. Sort X using `distance` as sorting key, then take the first **k** elements in the sorted dataset
2. Check **the distance frequency** and the the first occurrence of the most frequent distance

The alternative approach instead does the following steps:

1. Recover the **k** smallest elements in the `distance` column
2. Get the corresponding index value of the rows recovered in the previous step (for example with `k=5` it could be an element that when printed shows something similar to `Int64Index([3, 9, 10, 1, 8], dtype='int64')`
3. Recover in `y` the labels with the same index values of the ones recovered in the previous step
4. Get the **most frequent label** in `y` (or the `mode`)

So, as you can see, the main difference is the fact that the most frequent distance is not necessarily the most frequent class among the K neighbours that you have recovered.

Anyway you code can be easily fixed:

```
first_k = X_train['distance'].sort_values().head(k).index
prediction = y_train[first_k].mode()[0]
```